# Facebook sharing image not showing up

Tags: facebook, umbraco, facebook-opengraph, addthis, share-open-graph

I have implemented [AddThis](https://www.addthis.com) sharing functionality in my [Umbraco](https://umbraco.com/products/umbraco-cms/) CMS website.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="AddThis Tour" /> 
<meta property="og:description" content="Watch the AddThis Tour video." />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/1F7DKyFt5pY/default.jpg" />
```

In their documentation they mentioned if we pass image in meta tage like below it will showing up in share popup. I have puted all meta tags in my pages and tried that but image, description and title are not coming up from meta tags.

http://www.addthis.com/academy/how-to-optimize-facebook-sharing/

Even while in facebook popup window in URL Description, Title and Image are same as that provided in meta tags but in Actual sharing, it is displaying different title and description.

I tried Addtoany sharing tool but in that also not get success same thing happening in that also.

Comment: i cannot find og:image in the source

Comment: Facebook may me using cached sharing data for your page. You can use the [sharing debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/) to refresh the sharing data. It will also tell you if there are any issues with your sharing data, such as the image being too small for example.

Comment: @luschn you can find og:image in this url
https://www.incadea.com/blog/are-your-dms-and-other-systems-gdpr-compliant/

Comment: You need to add `https://` to your image URL, i.e. `<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.incadea.com/media/1595/incadea_how-to-assess-software-compliance-with-gdpr.png" />`. Also, you seem to have two `<head>` tags on your page. I suggest you try to merge these together.